# C# Convert List<string> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

This may seem an odd thing to want to do but ignoring that, is there a nice concise way of converting a `List<string>` to `Dictionary<string, string>` where each Key Value Pair in the Dictionary is just each string in the List. i.e.

```
List = string1, string2, string3
Dictionary = string1/string1, string2/string2, string3/string3
```

I have done plenty of searching and there are literally dozens of examples on Stackoverflow alone of doing it in the opposite direction but not this way round.

The reason for doing this is I have two third part components and changing them is out of my hands. One returns a list of email addresses as a `List<string>` and the other send emails where the To parameter is a `Dictionary<string, string>`. The key of the dictionary is the email address and the value is their real name. However, I don't know the real name but it still works if you set the real name to the email address as well. Therefore why I want to convert a List to a `Dictionary<string, string>`. There are plenty of ways of doing this. A `foreach` loop on the list which adds a kvp to a dictionary. But I like terse code and wondered if there was a single line solution.

Comment: I have a better solution for your valid reason, honest.

Comment: You may want to see if HashSet<> meets your requirements, instead of using Dictionary<,>.

Comment: More directly than the above commenters: If you explain your reason for wanting this, someone can probably suggest a better solution.

Comment: There is no better solution. I have a third party component that returns a list of strings these are email addresses. I have another third party component that sends emails where it passes a Dictionary<string, string> where the key is the email address and value is the recipients real name. However, the real name can also just be the email address again which is why I want to convert a List<string> to a Dictionary<string, string>

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = list.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
```

The first lambda lets you pick the key, the second one picks the value.

You can play with it and make values differ from the keys, like this:

```
var res = list.ToDictionary(x => x, x => string.Format("Val: {0}", x));
```

If your list contains duplicates, add `Distinct()` like this:

```
var res = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
```

**EDIT** To comment on the valid reason, I think the only reason that could be valid for conversions like this is that at some point the keys and the values in the resultant dictionary are going to diverge. For example, you would do an initial conversion, and then replace some of the values with something else. If the keys and the values are *always* going to be the same, `HashSet<String>` would provide a much better fit for your situation:

```
var res = new HashSet<string>(list);
if (res.Contains("string1")) ...
```

Comment: this will fail if list is like string1, string2, string3,string1

Comment: @PranayRana Yes, it would. You can add `.Distinct()` after `list` to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the ToDictionary function. Thanks to everyone who basically gave the same answer. I upvoted everyone but can only accept one answer. This one was only one with the Distinct code added so was the most complete in my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
var dict = list.ToDictionary(x => x);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb549277.aspx) for more info.

As Pranay points out in the comments, this will fail if an item exists in the list multiple times.
Depending on your specific requirements, you can either use `var dict = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x);` to get a dictionary of distinct items or you can use `ToLookup` instead:

```
var dict = list.ToLookup(x => x);
```

This will return an `ILookup<string, string>` which is essentially the same as `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`, so you will have a list of distinct keys with each string instance under it.

Comment: this will fail if list is like string1, string2, string3,string1

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT**

another way to deal with duplicate is you can do like this

```
var dic = slist.Select((element, index)=> new{element,index} )
            .ToDictionary(ele=>ele.index.ToString(), ele=>ele.element);
```

or

---

easy way to do is

```
var res = list.ToDictionary(str => str, str=> str);
```

**but make sure that there is no string is repeating...again otherewise above code will not work for you**

**if there is string is repeating than its better to do like this**

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic= new Dictionary<string,string> ();

    foreach(string s in Stringlist)
    {
       if(!dic.ContainsKey(s))
       {
        //  dic.Add( value to dictionary
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

By using [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx):

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(s => s);
```

If it is possible that any string could be repeated, either do a [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) call first on the list (to remove duplicates), or use [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) which allows for multiple values per key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(x => x);
```