# Trying to define WebMethod with dictionary as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm Using C#.

I'm trying to create a web method in my .asmx file as follow:

```
[WebMethod]
public string MyWebMethod(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
   //...
}
```

And I got the following exception:

```
The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `Dictionary` direct but you can use `list` as parameters

and this link can help you to convert `List` to `Dictionary`and continue your flow

[C# Convert List to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581101/c-sharp-convert-liststring-to-dictionarystring-string)