# how to join a list on new guids?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

**How do I join a list of strings with guids into a dictionary?**

I've got a list like so:

```
new List<String> { "alex", "liza", "harry" }
```

I'd like to create a dictionary like:

```
new Dictionary<Guid, String> {
        {
            "97085fe7-4717-4b70-95aa-80be9b1bfb47",
            "alex"
        },
        {
            "f88a41c2-27ac-47c5-a967-a4cdc2c6171c",
            "liza"
        },
        {
            "2a6adaac-23b4-4d6e-9fb4-610d4c14e231",
            "harry"
        }
    }
```

**How do I `zip` a *random* list of Guids together with a list of strings**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Convert List<string> to Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581101/c-sharp-convert-liststring-to-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: also... begs to question: why would you want this? because the context of your question might be leading to another question and another and completely different of your initial question

Comment: @riffnl indeed, great point hahahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var names = new List<String> { "alex", "liza", "harry" };

var d = names.ToDictionary(n => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ToDictionary` like so:

```
var myList = new List<String> { "alex", "liza", "harry" }
var myDictionary = myList.ToDictionary(i => Guid.NewGuid());

>>> Dictionary<Guid, string>(3) { { [06dde7e3-2fdd-4107-a4c5-63bee818abda], "alex" }, { [93029465-11b5-463b-ab04-bebdb1a8e77f], "liza" }, { [8ff8ff05-7bcf-4dd0-bb8d-07231932c3d8], "harry" }
```