# How to convert List<CustomType> to Dictionary<int, List<CustomType>>

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say that we have this custom type:

```
public class Holiday
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string holidayName { get; set; };
    public DateTime fromDate { get; set; };
    public DateTime toDate { get; set; };
    public int year { get; set; };
}
```

I need to convert list of Holidays (`List<Holiday>`) to an dictionary (`Dictionary<int, List<Holiday>>`). The keys are distinct years and the values are Lists of Holidays those belong to year.

I have tried to do that by looking at this [answer/Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581101/c-sharp-convert-liststring-to-dictionarystring-string)  but without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) method in LINQ, which

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key
>   selector function

In your case, the key would be `year` so the `GroupBy` syntax would look as follows:

```
List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>
{
    new Holiday
    {
        year = 1999,
        holidayName = "Easter"
    },
    new Holiday
    {
        year = 1999,
        holidayName = "Christmas"
    },
    new Holiday
    {
        year = 2000,
        holidayName = "Christmas"
    }
};

Dictionary<int, List<Holiday>> holidaysByYear = holidays
    .GroupBy(h => h.year)
    .ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.ToList());

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Holiday>> holidaysInYear in holidaysByYear)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Holidays in {holidaysInYear.Key}");
    foreach (Holiday holiday in holidaysInYear.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(holiday.holidayName);
    }
}
```

Which produces output as:

[image]